# Router Angular4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm developing a navigation service.
When I go from one page of the application to another, I save the address and the position of the scroll:

```
router.events.filter(e => e instanceof RoutesRecognized)
                .pairwise()
                .subscribe((e: [RoutesRecognized, RoutesRecognized]) => {    
                    this.prevUrl    = e[0].url;
                    this.saveScroll(this.prevUrl, window.pageYOffset); 
                });
```

Everything works well if we go the links. But...
If we go to the page using the browser buttons (forward and backward arrows), then window.pageYOffset(window.scrollY) assigned vallue position scroll future page, rather than the current.
I am hope for your help.